# MirrorLink Self-Signed Certificate with Android Studio

Tags: certificate, self-signed, mirrorlink

I am currently trying to get the MirrorLink example Application up and running.
When using the MirrorLink Plugin for Android Studio one can make use of the Wizard when creating a new Project.
https://causeway.carconnectivity.org/wg/DevWG/document/folder/570

This Wizard automatically creates a Gradle Script that generates a required self-signed.ccc.crt certificate to get Apps MirrorLink aware.

When I check the .apk with the provided Validator Tool https://causeway.carconnectivity.org/wg/DevWG/document/folder/570

I always get the following log output:

```
Checking com.mirrorlink.android.app.LAUNCH intent - OK
Checking com.mirrorlink.android.app.TERMINATE intent - OK
Checking com.mirrorlink.android.service.ACCESS_PERMISSION permission - OK
Checking DEVELOPER entity - OK
Checking if developer certificate exists for serverID="" - FAIL. 
Provided serverID is empty
Checking application id - OK
Checking self signed certificate - OK


The APK is not configured correctly.
```

The official documentation does not describe how to add a serverID to the certificate.

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The server ID is not used in the certificate, but is used by the Validator tool to check if the Developer Certificate Mechanism is configured correctly. If you put a Server ID in the text field labelled "Server ID for checking developer certificate" and then press the "Verify application" button, the Validator will use the server ID provided, and check to see if it is in your Developer Certificate.

Here's an example of what it looks like when all goes well (with part of the Server ID obscured):[image: APK Validator Screen Shot]